# How To Access Browser Error Messages from Script?

Tags: javascript

When running this script:

```
var myobj = document.createElement('script'); 
myobj.type = 'text/javascript';    
myobj.src = 'http://whateverpr0nsite.com';
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(myobj);
```

In the Chrome console, I see this message as the request gets blocked by a DNS porn filter:

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.0.0.1:2372/blockpage?id=36".`

I'm actually interested in the domain/IP address. Is there a way to access this information via JS? Or alternatively, via the `myobj` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.0.0.1:2372/blockpage?id=36"
```

Javascript has no control over this error message as when the  tag is constructed and append to the body, the js functionality is over.

Now the browser comes across this tag and makes the http request. As it finds that the link must end with .js extension and you have just provided a domain name, it gives mime error.

Comment: Any other way to get a random external website's IP address? I'm building a tool to test if inappropriate sites are blocked correctly.